# iptables - More verbose, full log

Tags: debian, iptables

I set the following rules:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -j LOG
iptables -A INPUT -j LOG
```

and checking the logs with

```
iptables -vnL
```

The results is not what I want; I don't want to see source destination `0.0.0.0/0` and prot(ocoll) `all` what I want is to see per protocol/port and which process is trying to access the ports.

Comment: it looks like you'll need to post process the logs and watch /proc/net/tcp or use other tools for climbing back to processes. Just many suggestions could be found in the  following thread https://superuser.com/questions/34782/with-linux-iptables-is-it-possible-to-log-the-process-command-name-that-initiat

Answer (score 0):

> what I want is to see per protocol/port and which process is trying to access the ports.

`iptables` isn't the right tool to see protocol/port/service. But you can use `ss` (or `netstat`), `lsof` and `nmap` or by checking the `/etc/services` file.

e,g:

```
sudo ss -tulpn
less /etc/services
sudo lsof -i -Pn | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: the problem is that using ss, netstat, nmap etc I get a "snapshot" at that time, is not like continuing logging for a longer period of time.